# is this a good way to implement a http request to an api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning how to use third party API and wanted to know if what I have is a good way to implement an HTTP request to an API. I created a private method which is used to display information to front end, I did it this way so I don't put everything in GetResult() Method. is there a better way to do it?

UPDATE 2

```
  public ActionResult Main()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetResult(int zipCode)
        {
            ApiController api = new ApiController();
            var weather = api.GetResult(zipCode);

            var tuple = new Tuple<OpenWeatherMap, RootObject>(new OpenWeatherMap(), new RootObject());

            return View("Main", tuple);
        }
 public async Task<Json.RootObject> GetResult(int zipCode)
        {
            const string apiKey = "";
            var client = new HttpClient();


            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" +
                                                 zipCode + ",us&APPID=" + apiKey);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var rootObj = new Json.RootObject();

            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json.RootObject>(responseBody);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                rootObj.id = deserialize.id;
                rootObj.weather[0].description = deserialize.weather[0].description;
            }

            return rootObj;
        }
```

Comment: instead of calling the API directly in your view. You should do this in your own API controller. Use JS to call your own API endpoint and forward it to the 3rd party one.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep you requests to other systems hidden behind a [Gateway](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html) and keep all the gory details about the external API there.  Also [best practice](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) is to use one HttpClient per application because they have a design flaw that holds on to sockets after they are disposed.

If you are using dotnet core, then use HttpClientFactory get an instance of a pooled HttpClient

For the HttpClient creation in your Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public static HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }


    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    }


    protected void Application_End()
    {
        if (HttpClient == null) return;

        HttpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

A naive implementation might be

```
public class ExternalGateway
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ExternalGateway(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<SomeModel> GetSomeExternalResource(Uri uri)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri.AbsoluteUri);

        // TODO: check status
        // do some conversion of the content to your model

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeModel>(content);
    }
}

public class SomeModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

replacing you model and the url you want to connect to.

Then your controller can stay clean.

something like

```
        var gateway = new ExternalGateway(MvcApplication.HttpClient);
        var model = await gateway.GetSomeExternalResource(new Uri("<your complete url>"));

        return View(model);
```

This assumes that your are going to use a strongly typed model with your view instead of the ViewBag.

Comment: So I should create a class where I call the api and use that data in a view in controller?

Comment: yes.  you can call the method on the class and pass what's returned to your View.

Comment: I will try it out and give an update for further questions.

Comment: While you state *one HttpClient per application*, your example does not do that.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I could certainly add something to the example. Easiest thing the op could do would to put a static property on the application for the HttpClient and reference.  Not my preferred approach, but it would work

Comment: @Fran as it stands because you don't dispose of the HttpClient you're leaving the conneciton open and because it's not static, it's recreated everytime someone needs a gateway.

Comment: @ErikPhilips i purposefully didn't put how the HttpClient was instantiated because I thought it was greater than the scope of the question.  The article I linked to explained this issue and how to fix it.

Comment: @Fran so it's Ok to give a known bad example?